# How to spyOn a function which has an Promise inside and don't return the result but handles the response itself?

Tags: jasmine, es6-modules

How can I spyOn a method called placed in the object?

```
// Game.js

export default {
    mine: null,

    handle: function(me) {
        console.log("   FOOOOO " + me)
    },

    setSource: function() {
        this.mine.getSource().then((response) => {
          const {source} = response
          this.handle(source)
        })
    }
}
```

Here i try to spy:

```
// GameSpec.js

import Game from '../../lib/jasmine_examples/Game'

Game.mine = {}

describe("Game", function() {
  it("should set source and handle it", function() {

    Game.mine.getSource = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve( {
          source : 'BAAAAR'
        })
      })
    }

    spyOn(Game, 'handle').and.callThrough()

    Game.setSource()

    expect(Game.handle).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
});
```

In the output you can see the function "handle" was called:

```
Started
F   FOOOOO BAAAAR


Failures:
1) Game should set source and handle it
  Message:
    Expected spy handle to have been called.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected spy handle to have been called.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/silverbook/Sites/zTest/jasmine/spec/jasmine_examples/PlayerSpec.js:20:29)
        at <Jasmine>

1 spec, 1 failure
```

But `jasmine` says it was not called.

If i remove the mocked `Promise` the test passes but i needed there. In another test i will return an error in the Promise and let it handle from another function.

So the `Promise` breaks the test but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test executes synchronously and the `expect` fails before the callback queued by `this.mine.getSource().then()` has a chance to execute.

For `Jasmine` >= 2.7 and `async` function support you can convert your test function into an `async` function and add an `await Promise.resolve();` where you want to pause the synchronous test and let any queued callbacks execute.

For your test it would look like this:

```
import Game from '../../lib/jasmine_examples/Game'

Game.mine = {}

describe("Game", function() {
  it("should set source and handle it", async () => {

    Game.mine.getSource = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve( {
          source : 'BAAAAR'
        })
      })
    }
    spyOn(Game, 'handle').and.callThrough();

    Game.setSource();

    await Promise.resolve(); // let the event loop cycle

    expect(Game.handle).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

For older (>= 2.0) `Jasmine` versions you can use `done()` like this:

```
import Game from '../../lib/jasmine_examples/Game'

Game.mine = {}

describe("Game", function() {
  it("should set source and handle it", (done) => {

    Game.mine.getSource = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve( {
          source : 'BAAAAR'
        })
      })
    }
    spyOn(Game, 'handle').and.callThrough();

    Game.setSource();

    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(Game.handle).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It produces this error `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulGeisler that error means you don't have an `async` polyfill set up, I've added an example for older versions of `Jasmine` and/or no `async` support, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Yes, you're right - we use Jasmine 2.x. Your solution worked, thank you!

Comment: @PaulGeisler awesome! 

Answer (score 2):

You can run the test inside `fakeAsync` and run `tick()` before the `expect()`

*Service:*

```
getFirebaseDoc() {   
  this.db.firestore.doc('some-doc').get()
    .then(this.getFirebaseDocThen)
    .catch(this.getFirebaseDocCatch);
}
```

*Unit testing:*

```
it('should call getFirebaseDocThen', fakeAsync(() => {          // note `fakeAsync`
    spyOn(service, 'getFirebaseDocThen');
    spyOn(service.db.firestore, 'doc').and.returnValue({
      get: (): any => {
        return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any): any => {
          return resolve({ exists: true });
        });
      },
    });
    service.getFirebaseDoc();
    tick();                                                     // note `tick()`
    expect(service.getFirebaseDocThen).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```